# Difference between pseudo-convergence and initial transient problem

Tags: convergence-divergence, markov-chains, monte-carlo

I am trying to understand the difference of the initial transient problem and pseudo-convergence when it comes to MCMC convergence diagnostics.

I found the following explanations for the problems:

> The term “initial transient” refers to that initial segment of the simulation that is
> contaminated by bias introduced by starting the system in some state that is
> not typical of the long-run behavior of the system.

> A Markov chain can appear to have converged to its equilibrium distribution when it has
> not. This happens when parts of the state space are poorly connected by the Markov chain
> dynamics: it takes many iterations to get from one part to another. When the time it takes to
> transition between these parts is much longer than the length of simulated Markov chain,
> then the Markov chain can appear to have converged but the distribution it appears to have
> converged to is the equilibrium distribution conditioned on the part in which the chain was
> started. We call this phenomenon pseudo-convergence.

I have troubles to differentiate between the two problems. Both depend on the starting value of the chain. The initial transient problem is resolved by including a "warm-up" / removing samples influence by the initializing value. Pseudo-convergence has to be detected by diagnostics such as multi-chain approaches or investigating long-term behavior and then has to be addressed differently.

Can the two be clearly differentiated?
Because to me, they seem to be connected where pseudo-convergence is a "extension" of the initial transient problem. If for instance, the chain is initialized in a area that is not typical for long term behavior and the state spaces are poorly connected in my mind that would lead to pseudo-convergence.

Do you think these two things are connected? If not, could you explain the difference?

References:

*Asmussen, Søren; Glynn, Peter W.; Thorisson, Hermann*, [**Stationarity detection in the initial transient problem**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1145/137926.137932), ACM Trans. Model. Comput. Simul. 2, No. 2, 130-157 (1992). [ZBL0842.68106](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0842.68106).>

*Geyer, Charles J.*, Introduction to Markov chain Monte Carlo, Brooks, Steve (ed.) et al., Handbook of Markov chain Monte Carlo. Boca Raton, FL: CRC Press (ISBN 978-1-4200-7941-8/hbk; 978-1-4200-7942-5/ebook). Chapman & Hall/CRC Handbooks of Modern Statistical Methods, 3-48 (2011). [ZBL1229.65014](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1229.65014).